# RSA implementation in c using gmp

Tags: c, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, gmp

I have wrote this program that successfully encrypt & decrypt the message. Then I added the code that see if there is another private key that pair the same public key, things got comfusing.

Anyway, the code will show everything. Thank you for viewing my question.

I was expecting the message I encrypted by the public-key I just generated which in the below code to be able to decrypted by the only private-key I generate. But after it successfully decryptd the message, I got another private-key that can decrypt the message.

I think it's a lots easier to understand me just reading the code, sorry for the lack of detail. I don't know what's going on.

If a public-key encrypted message can be decrypted by many other private-key, then why is this algorithm secure?

```
// Module
 // System
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <limits.h>
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <time.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <gmp.h>
  // sys
   #include <sys/time.h>
   #include <sys/file.h>
 // Homemade
  #include "/root/01_Code/03_C/00_Module/output_option.h"
  //
// main()
 int main(void){
  // Value
   // Basic
    long   Loop  [1];
    time_t Seed;
    long   Level = 8;
    gmp_randstate_t Random_State; gmp_randinit_default(Random_State);
   // RSA
    mpz_t Buffer_mpz_1; mpz_init(Buffer_mpz_1);
    mpz_t Buffer_mpz_2; mpz_init(Buffer_mpz_2);
    mpz_t Prime_1;      mpz_init(Prime_1);
    mpz_t Prime_2;      mpz_init(Prime_2);
    mpz_t Phi;          mpz_init(Phi);
    mpz_t Common_Key;   mpz_init(Common_Key);
    mpz_t Public_Key;   mpz_init(Public_Key);
    mpz_t Private_Key;  mpz_init(Private_Key);
  // Implementation
   // RSA init
    // Prime_1
     sleep(1);
     time(&Seed);
     gmp_randseed_ui(Random_State, Seed);
     mpz_urandomb(Prime_1, Random_State, Level);
     while(mpz_probab_prime_p(Prime_1, 49) != 2)
      mpz_add_ui(Prime_1, Prime_1, 1);
    // Prime_2
     sleep(1);
     time(&Seed);
     gmp_randseed_ui(Random_State, Seed);
     mpz_urandomb(Prime_2, Random_State, Level);
     while(mpz_probab_prime_p(Prime_2, 49) != 2)
      mpz_add_ui(Prime_2, Prime_2, 1);
    // Phi
     mpz_sub_ui(Phi,          Prime_1, 1);
     mpz_sub_ui(Buffer_mpz_1, Prime_2, 1);
     mpz_mul(   Phi,          Phi,     Buffer_mpz_1);
    // Common_Key
     mpz_mul(Common_Key, Prime_1, Prime_2);
     //
    // Public_Key
     // Init random Public_Key
      do{
       sleep(1);
       time(&Seed);
       gmp_randseed_ui(Random_State, Seed);
       mpz_urandomb(Public_Key, Random_State, Level);
      }while(mpz_cmp(Public_Key, Phi) >= 0 || mpz_cmp_ui(Public_Key, 1) == 0);
      mpz_set(Buffer_mpz_2, Public_Key);
     // Pick Public_Key
      while(1){
       if(mpz_cmp(Public_Key, Phi) < 0){
        mpz_gcd(Buffer_mpz_1, Public_Key, Phi);
        if(mpz_cmp_ui(Buffer_mpz_1, 1) == 0) break;
        mpz_add_ui(Public_Key, Public_Key, 1);
       }else{
        mpz_set(Public_Key, Buffer_mpz_2);
        while(1){
         mpz_sub_ui(Public_Key, Public_Key, 1);
         if(mpz_cmp_ui(Public_Key, 1) == 0){
          printf("%d\n", __LINE__);
          mpz_clear(Buffer_mpz_1);
          mpz_clear(Buffer_mpz_2);
          mpz_clear(Prime_1);
          mpz_clear(Prime_2);
          mpz_clear(Phi);
          mpz_clear(Common_Key);
          mpz_clear(Public_Key);
          mpz_clear(Private_Key);
          return 1;
         }
         mpz_gcd(Buffer_mpz_1, Public_Key, Phi);
         if(mpz_cmp_ui(Buffer_mpz_1, 1) == 0) goto l_END_PK;
        }
       }
      }
      l_END_PK:;
    // Private_Key
     mpz_set_ui(Buffer_mpz_1, 1);
     mpz_set_ui(Private_Key,  2); char Switch = 'V';
     l_AGAIN:do{
      mpz_add_ui(Private_Key, Private_Key, 1);
      mpz_mul(Buffer_mpz_1, Public_Key,   Private_Key);
      mpz_mod(Buffer_mpz_1, Buffer_mpz_1, Phi);
     }while(mpz_cmp_ui(Buffer_mpz_1, 1) != 0);
     if(Switch == 'V'){
      Switch = 'X';
      mpz_set(Buffer_mpz_2, Private_Key);
      goto l_AGAIN;
     }
   // Encrypt & Decrypt
    mpz_set_ui(Buffer_mpz_1, 88);
    mpz_powm(Buffer_mpz_1, Buffer_mpz_1, Public_Key,  Common_Key);
    mpz_powm(Buffer_mpz_1, Buffer_mpz_1, Private_Key, Common_Key);
    gmp_printf("Prime_1     %Zd\n", Prime_1);
    gmp_printf("Prime_2     %Zd\n", Prime_2);
    gmp_printf("Public_Key  %Zd\n", Public_Key);
    gmp_printf("Private_Key %Zd\n", Private_Key);
    gmp_printf("Common_Key  %Zd\n", Common_Key);
    gmp_printf("Decrypted   %Zd\n", Buffer_mpz_1);
    printf("----------------------------------------------------\n");
    mpz_set_ui(Buffer_mpz_1, 88);
    mpz_powm(Buffer_mpz_1, Buffer_mpz_1, Public_Key,   Common_Key);
    mpz_powm(Buffer_mpz_1, Buffer_mpz_1, Buffer_mpz_2, Common_Key);
    gmp_printf("Prime_1     %Zd\n", Prime_1);
    gmp_printf("Prime_2     %Zd\n", Prime_2);
    gmp_printf("Public_Key  %Zd\n", Public_Key);
    gmp_printf("Private_Key %Zd\n", Buffer_mpz_2);
    gmp_printf("Common_Key  %Zd\n", Common_Key);
    gmp_printf("Decrypted   %Zd\n", Buffer_mpz_1);
  // Clean up
   mpz_clear(Buffer_mpz_1);
   mpz_clear(Buffer_mpz_2);
   mpz_clear(Prime_1);
   mpz_clear(Prime_2);
   mpz_clear(Phi);
   mpz_clear(Common_Key);
   mpz_clear(Public_Key);
   mpz_clear(Private_Key);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Things got confusing once you introduced goto's instead of dividing the program into smaller functions and using proper control constructs.

Comment: Your question is...?

Comment: @StoryTeller I know goto is dangerous, but in this case I don't think it's the problem. That part is just because I'm lazy. XD, Thanks

Comment: Voted to close because there isn't a question. What goes wrong? What output are you seeing? What output did you get?

Comment: @lvella Sorry, I'll complete the question. If a public-key encrypted message can be decrypted by many other private-key, then why is this algorithm secure

Comment: @JeremyP Sorry, maybe because I open this question with my phone, it lacks some detail. I'm adding it

Comment: For RSA the private key is unique mod lamba(N), which means any d + k * 
 lambda(N) is a valid private key. It's secure because nobody knows a way to efficiently determine *any* of the equivalent private keys.

Comment: @JamesKPolk so why I got the second private-key and successfully decrypted the message again with the second private-key in my code? It shouldn't be unique? Or just because my code went wrong?

Comment: Your code is unreadable.

Comment: @JamesKPolk can't be that bad....

Comment: Ok, so I ran your code, and it turns out I answered your question in my previous comment. So I'll try again. For RSA the private key is unique mod [lambda(N)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), which means any d + k * lambda(N) is a valid private key. It's secure because nobody knows a way to efficiently determine any of the equivalent private keys.

Comment: @JamesKPolk  My math sucks, but I just check a tutorial. All his number fits my code, so I guess my code is right. What I dont understand is, if a public-key encrypted message can be decrypted by so many private-key, wouldn't it be easier to be brute-force attacked? Cause I added a loop to get more private-key, then I got the number running like hell. Maybe I should try to crack it to feel how hard is it or fix my math hope one day I will understand it?

Comment: @user7750945 It's not that much easier to brute force, because in the formula that James supplied a high `k` just increases the numbers that you have to work with and they are too far apart that you can work with them. RSA is broken through factoring which is much easier than hoping that this helps you in any way.

Comment: Why not use  `mpz_clears` and `mpz_inits` to make code easier to read? These are variadic functions. You need to send in `NULL` to tell the function that is the end of arguments:   `mpz_inits(a, b, c, NULL);`